Do any denominations/sources include hemolymph in their opposition to blood consumption?
Among the religious organizations and sources that discourage blood consumption, do any extend the principle to hemolymph, the equivalent of blood in creatures such as locusts and oysters? While organizations that require a kosher diet would prohibit shellfish already, even kosher diets include locusts, so this question is applicable to any denomination or other source that discourages blood consumption.

The problem (which I often run into myself) is that you are basically asking for a list, which won't really give you a definite correct answer. We seem to tolerate that more than the right of the SE though.
